# Bitwise Logical Operations coerce to integer not intuitive in R

Tags: r, bitwise-operators, type-conversion

Should bitw* function use round to coerce to integer rather than as.integer?

```
str((6.6-6)*10)
#num 6
bitwShiftL(1,(6.6-6)*10)
#[1] 32
bitwShiftL(1,6)
#[1] 64
```

This is due to the fact that Bitwise Logical Operations coerce to integer and as.integer does trunc. In our case (6.6-6)*10 is internally stored as 5.99999... which is ok (see [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal?noredirect=1&lq=1))

I would assume that someone writing bitwShiftL(1,5.9) is actually willing to shift by 6 rather than 5.

Comment: Coercing float to int means flooring (i.e., cutting the mantisse) in any programming language I know. So one should not change this paradigm in R...

Comment: ok for float to int conversion, bit wouldn't it be better to round the argument within bitwShift[R|L] instead of coercing to int? It seems that I am not the only one who had shifted by 5 when I was expecting to shift by 6.